# looping thru a python list and display results in flask

Tags: python, jinja2

python function returns a python list

python module function

```
with open(xml_append_back) as fd1:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd1.read())
    codes = []

    for p in doc['Des']['Config']:
            codes.append(p['@Id'])
            codes.append(pl['@name'])


print(codes)
return codes

codes = ['f2ee4681', 'Conf. no: 1', '89282c5b', 'Conf. no: 2', '3e9dd219', 'Conf. no: 3', '773044b9'] # returned from python  to flask template result.html
```

I call this variable in my templates/flask.html like this
flask file

```
@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():

const_ids=run_d.run_de_selected_configs() # this function returns "codes" 

return render_template("result.html",result = 
constraint_names_from_form,result1=constraint_ids)
```

result.html file

```
{% for key,key1  in result1 %}
<tr class="even"><td>{{ key }}</td><td>{{ key1 }}</td></tr>
```

should be

```
<tr class="even"><td>f2ee4681</td><td>Conf. no: 1</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Please add a description of the problem (what goes wrong?) and all code required to solve the problem.

Comment: Show us the template render call.  As it is, you've given us a python variable called `codes` and a template variable called `result`, and we have no idea how those are supposed to be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your code is packing all the `Id` and `name` values into a single flat list. That doesn't work right when you later need to iterate over it, as you want two values per iteration and you're only getting one.

While there are some ways to iterate over pairs from a list (e.g. `zip(*[iter(x)]*2)`), I would suggest that you just build a list of tuples directly.

Try changing:

```
        codes.append(planet['@Id'])
        codes.append(planet['@name'])
```

To:

```
        codes.append((planet['@Id'], planet['@name']))
```

Comment: Any changes in the for loop in result.html ?

Comment: I'm not a jinja expert, but I don't think any changes should be necessary. Your original code didn't work because it was trying to unpack two values per iteration (I'd expect exceptions, but you haven't actually said what was going wrong, and the template might have made things ugly to debug). With a list of tuples, the loop should just work.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question 
I used zip utility in my python code as zip is not available in flask

```
function returncodes()
-------
--------- 

return zip(codes,codeNames) # in my case
```

no change in the flask template

```
@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():

const_ids=run_d.run_de_selected_configs() # this function returns "codes" 

return render_template("result.html",result = 
constraint_names_from_form,result1=constraint_ids)
```

now in my result.html

```
{% for keys,keys2 in result1 %}
<tr class="even"><td>{{keys}}</td><td>{{keys2}}</td></tr>

 {% endfor %}
```